# ApexCharts Tooltip on radar chart's filled area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to be active tooltip on radar chart when hovering filled area of radar.

I just look documentation of ApexCharts but there is no option about that(or I didn't see that).

if can help me about that I really be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apexchart has an option property that allow you to enable or disable some options. Tooltip is one of those options

See the following: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/